# IAP Mandatory to use other than Stripe?

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

My Application got rejected Recently with following error

Guideline 3.1.1 - Business - Payments - In-App Purchase

We noticed that your app offers a subscription with a mechanism other than the in-app purchase API.

Next Steps

To resolve this issue, please revise your app to ensure that the subscription for products used within the app is offered using the in-app purchase API, with the exception of the content specified in guideline 3.1.3 of the App Store Review Guidelines.

In-App Purchase

It may be appropriate to revise your app to use the in-app purchase API to provide content purchasing functionality.

In-app purchase provides several benefits, including:

- The flexibility to support a variety of business models.
- Impacting your app ranking by consolidating your sales to one app rather than distributing them across multiple apps.
- An effective marketing vehicle to drive additional sales of new content.

For step-by-step instructions on in-app purchase creation within App Store Connect, refer to App Store Connect Help.

Answer (score 1):

You can't sell subscription using `Stripe`, because it's a digital property.

---

More info:

> There are a couple different ways to integrate payments into your iOS
>   app: Apple Pay and In-App Purchases. It’s important to understand when
>   each option should be used.
>
> You can use Apple Pay to sell physical goods such as groceries,
>   clothing, and appliances. Also use Apple Pay for services such as club
>   memberships, hotel reservations, and tickets for events. These
>   transactions will be processed through Stripe and you’ll only need to
>   pay Stripe’s processing fee. You can read more about Apple Pay here.
>
> You are required to use Apple’s In-App Purchase API to sell virtual
>   goods such as premium content for your app, and subscriptions for
>   digital content. Specifically, Apple’s developer terms require that
>   the In-App Purchase API must be used for digital “content,
>   functionality, or services” such as premium features or credits. If
>   you use the In-App Purchase API, the transactions will be processed by
>   Apple, which will charge a fee of 30% of the total transaction.

---

Docs: https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios#using-stripe-and-apple-pay-vs-in-app-purchases

Comment: So, using Apple Pay to create a payment token and use stripe as way to pay payment of a subscription using Apple Pay token will get approved ?

Comment: @JatinGarg If you are selling digital good, you can use **only** in app purchases. Stripe with Apple Pay can be used for physical goods.

Comment: *You are required to use Apple’s In-App Purchase API to sell virtual goods such as premium content for your app, and subscriptions for digital content.*

Comment: Sorry if I am not getting what you mean ? its just using Apple Pay to make payment and process its token with stripe will let me cross apple guidelines ? as I will use Apple Pay (Apple inapp purchase API)

Comment: You can't use Stripe. You **must** use Apple's in app purchases and pay them 30%, because you sell digital good.

Comment: Apple in-app purchases and Apple Pay are different things. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a payment gateway other than InApp purchase to offer soft services/digital good transactions(Any functionality within the app) in your app.